# Set Variables instead of User Input

Tags: javascript, function

This function is receiving two pieces of data from the end-user via HTML form, `#from` and `#to`.  I would like them to come from set variables, instead of user input (i.e. `#directions-form`).  How do I go about doing that?

```
$('#directions-form').submit(function(e) {
  $('#error').hide();
  ds.route({
    origin: $('#from').val(),
    destination: $('#to').val(),
    travelMode: $('#mode').val()
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      fitBounds = true;
      dr.setDirections(result);
    }
    else {
      $('#error').text(status).show();
    }
    recalcHeight();
  });
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Please rephrase as your current question is not clear.

Comment: I just rephrased, does it make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is replace the values with the variables.  For example, it might look like this:

```
origin: myOrigin,
destination: myDestination,
```

There's nothing inherently special about the code as it currently stands.  All this is doing:

```
$('#from').val()
```

is dynamically fetching a value from an input element on the form called `from`.  This evaluates into a value just like a variable does, it's just not storing that value in a variable but instead fetching it directly from the HTML.  You can directly replace it with a variable.

**Update:** In your PasteBin in the comments below is looks like you're calling the function incorrectly here:

```
ds.route(from,to,mode);
```

That function takes two parameters, the first of which is an object composed of the three values you're trying to pass to it and the second is the callback function.  Something like this:

```
ds.route({
  origin: from,
  destination: to,
  travelMode: mode
}, function(result, status) {
  // Here you can respond to the results in some way
});
```

Comment: I did as advised, but the function is still dependent on the ('#directions-form').submit, it is not taking the two variables that I defined and using those.  Any ideas?

Comment: @benknighthorse: Well, you didn't ask about the form submit.  Currently the entire function (`ds.route()`) is set to be executed when the form submits.  If you want to execute it on some other event or at some other time in code, just call the `ds.route()` function where you need to call it.

Comment: is there a way I can link the entire code, so everyone can get a better idea of what I am after?

Comment: @benknighthorse: You could supply a jsFiddle link or PasteBin link I suppose.  It's best to keep it only to relevant code or perhaps a somewhat contrived example, though.  Just posting in an entire codebase is usually frowned upon since it's filled with unrelated things.  At the moment it really just sounds like you're trying to manually call the `ds.route()` function, which you can do.  All you need to do is pass in a structure with the 3 values it needs and pass in a function for it to call when it's done.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I wasn't passing it the 3 variables that it needed.  I will try that and report back.

Comment: it didn't work like I thought it would. [link](http://pastebin.com/1qKeanUF)

Comment: Were you able to take a look at that pastebin @David ?

Comment: @benknighthorse: Briefly, I've updated the answer with some help.  You were close, but it looks like you definitely need more practice understanding how function calls work, how parameters are passed to them, and how to construct objects.  It's close, but you can't just pass those values to the function like that.  It expects them to be in a single object.

Comment: Thank you for the update @David . I just updated the code and here is a new [link](http://pastebin.com/DtXq950C) .  I have set the variables and I am passing them into the function, correctly.  I don't understand why on page load this function is not being called and supplying the correct data.  I am not asking for any user input at this point, it seems that it should just be running when the script is loaded.  Is that not what happens when you simply call the function ds.route ?

Comment: @benknighthorse: I'll bet there are JavaScript errors in your browser's console that you're not looking at.  It looks like you commented out part of the `submit` handler function, but not the end of it.  So the whole script is likely failing to parse.  For reference, here's a stripped-down working version I just created: http://jsfiddle.net/cr4Cu/

Comment: Thank you @David ! I was able to get that working!  Now, onto the elevation portion! :)

Answer (score 1):

The following will remove the coupling between the UI element and the callback

```
var to = $('#to').val();// or some arbitrary other source that contains the value you want to assign
var from = $('#from').val();
$('#directions-form').submit(function(e) {
  $('#error').hide();
  ds.route({
    origin: from,
    destination: to,
    travelMode: $('#mode').val()
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      fitBounds = true;
      dr.setDirections(result);
    }
    else {
      $('#error').text(status).show();
    }
    recalcHeight();
  });
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: then I can set var to = lat|long and var from = lat|long, and that should solve my question?

Comment: You can apply whatever logic you want when assigning these two variables. The end result will be assigned to the origin and destination propertied